# undefined method `albums_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, paperclip

I dont understand why this is happening but I am getting this error. 
`undefined method albums_path` and it says that it is on the first line in this code:

```
<%= form_for @album, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal', multipart: true } do |f| %> 
    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
```

but I dont see why. here is my controller:

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_album, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @albums = Album.all.where(:user_id => @user)
  end

  def show
    redirect_to user_albums_url
  end

  def new
    @album = Album.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create

    @album = current_user.albums.new(album_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @album.save

        if params[:images]
          params[:images].each { |image|
            @album.pictures.create(image: image)
          }
        end
          format.html { redirect_to @album, notice: 'Gallery was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render json: @album, status: :created, location: @album }
      else
          format.html { render action: "new" }
          format.json { render json: @album.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity } 
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @album.update(album_params)
    redirect_to user_albums_url
  end

  def destroy
    @album.destroy
    redirect_to user_albums_url
  end

  private
    def set_album
      @album = Album.find(params[:id])
    end

    def album_params
      params.require(:album).permit(:name, :description, :images)
    end
end
```

and my routes are as follows:

```
resources :users do
    resources :albums do
      resources :pictures do
        resources :comments
      end
    end
  end
```

Ive looked everywhere for my code even mentioning "albums_path" but it doesnt say it anywhere. Is there anything that you guys can think of being the problem? I've tried fixing the forms but it doesnt seem to work. another thing that you might want to see is the link to new action. here it is:

```
<%= link_to 'New Album', new_user_album_path(:user_id => current_user.id), :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
```

I don't know if this helps at all but I'm using the paperclip gem to create albums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `albums` resource is nested within `users` resource. Therefore you should set user in your `new` action (or, better, in `before_filter`):

```
before_filter :set_user
# ...
def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end
```

and add user reference to your form:

```
form_for [@user, @album] do |f|
```

BTW, instead of `@albums = Album.all.where(:user_id => @user)`, you can have (it's much more idiomatic in Rails): `@albums = @user.albums`.

Comment: worked great! but now when I go to create a new album it is saying `undefined method album_url` and points to this line: `format.html { redirect_to @album, notice: 'Gallery was successfully created.' }` in the create method of my albums controller...

Comment: @DylanLittle same story. `redirect_to [@user, @album]`. I advice you to learn something about nested resources in Rails.